# bootstrap second carousel other css rules

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I used the Bootstrap carousel for showing images. But on the same page i've two different carousels. Now i want to give the one carousel other css rules than the second. But when i changed the one, the second one will do the same css rules. This is my code:

```
<div id="myCarousel_port" class="carousel_port">
<div class="carousel-inner" id="carousel_portfolio">
<?php
$args = array (
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => array('post','werk')
  );
  $home_recent = new WP_Query( $args );
  if( $home_recent ->have_posts() ) :
  while( $home_recent ->have_posts() ) :
  $home_recent ->the_post(); 
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
  $image = get_field('foto');
  //Voor de eerste active item te tonen ?>
  <div class="item active">
  <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" width="100%">
  <p><?php the_field('materiaal'); ?></p>
   <p><?php the_field('afmetingen'); ?></p>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

And my CSS file:

```
#carousel_portfolio
width: 100%
min-height: 70vh
text-align: right
text-indent: 10px

.carousel_port
width: 60%
min-height: 50vh
margin-left: 20%
margin-top: 2px
```

For CSS i used SASS. I've bootstrap include with an url from getbootstrap.com. Is there anybody who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to apply your css with different class or ids

like

```
.carousel1 img{
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel2 img{
  width: 80%;
}


<div class="carousel1">
   <img src="someimg.jpg">
</div>

<div class="carousel2">
   <img src="someimg.jpg">
</div>
```

hope you got my point

Comment: It works, only the carousel didn't work. He shows all the images.